# Pull out Comma Seperated String from EntitySet<T>

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I convert `EntitySet<>` to a String?  i.e. (bob, joe, frank)?

In the below LINQ `ContactType` is a seperate table that can have numerous values.  I am trying to convert it into a comma seperated string.

```
var caseNotes =context.tblCaseNotes
                .Where(cn => cn.PersonID == personID)
                .OrderBy(cn => cn.ContactDate)
                .Select(cn => new
                            {
                                cn.ContactDate,
                                cn.ContactDetails,
                                cn.TimeSpentUnits,
                                cn.IsCaseLog,
                                cn.IsPreEnrollment,
                                cn.PresentAtContact,
                                ContactType = string.Join(", ", cn.tblCaseNoteContactTypes.ToArray()),
                                cn.InsertDate,
                                cn.InsertUser,
                                cn.CaseNoteID,
                                cn.ParentNote
                            });
```

Comment: What error do you get? I think I can guess it, but it's probably faster and easier if you just tell us instead of making us guess.

Comment: Sorry, I get an error stating that I can't assign `EntitySet<tblCaseNoteContactType> as parameter string[]`

Comment: Is my problem that `tblCaseNotesContactTypes` is more then just strings?  It has 3 columns; GUID, GUID, Int.  The Int relates to an Admin Table which is where the Description would be.  As I type this out I can see I was way off!  I need to do it quite different....

Comment: what type is tblCaseNoteContactType?

Comment: Please, edit your question to reflect the missing info. You can also remove the not needed information (most ot the `cn...` lines).

Comment: it is a Linq To SQL Table, I should have been clearer in the beginning.  Much thanks to @Magnus for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select which column from `tblCaseNoteContactTypes` you want to concat

```
 ContactType = string.Join(", ", 
         cn.tblCaseNoteContactTypes.Select(x => x.MyColumn))
```

Comment: SWEET!  This is almost what I was looking for, I get a `IEnumerable<String> is not assignable to String[]`....thoughts?

Comment: I added a `.ToArray()` and the world is good!  Thanks
`string.Join(", ", cn.tblCaseNoteContactTypes.Select(x => x.tblCaseNotesMaintItem.ItemDescription).ToArray())`

Comment: [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) takes in `IEnumerable<string>` as the 2'nd parameter in framework 4. If you are using older version you need the `ToArray()`

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  I am still, sadly, on 3.5.  It's running grand now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Append `.ToArray();` at the end of your LINQ query, and use it as parameter for `String.Join()`

```
String.Join(", ", yourLinqQuery.ToArray());
```

For this to work, your LINQ query must return a string, so that the Array is a array of string. Or an object who has a `ToString()` that matches what you want.

[String.Join(string, object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx)

EDIT: as you added new info:

If tblCaseNotesContactTypes is an object, you need to add a `.Select(t -> {return t converted to string})` before the `.ToArray()`

Comment: I am pretty sure this is what I already have up in my example, no?

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty?

`ContactType = cn.tblCaseNoteContactTypes.Any() ? string.Join(", ", cn.tblCaseNoteContactTypes.ToArray()) : String.Empty`

Also,

`tblCaseNoteContactTypes`

If the members of this collection aren't strings, `Join` is going to have some trouble.